# Chrome does not send client certificate, while certificate is valid

Tags: ssl, client-certificates, mutual-authentication

I am witnessing a weird issue with regards to mutual authentication.
I have setup mutual authentication on BigIP loadbalancer to accept 2 different CAs.
This means that we only accept certificates that has been issued by those 2 CAs.

I have tried providing those certificates to LB using OpenSSL and it works fine by this i mean i have 2 certificate, Using IE it works fine as well, FireFox it works fine as well. but when i use chrome, browser asks for certificate but it doesnt send the certificate to the LB, as it has been observed in wiresharks (Picture to follow)

I have access to both certificates, so i extacted the certs and key and used

```
openssl s_client -connect Host:port -cert "cert.pem" -key "key.pem"
```

It works fine, and i can see connection is ok.

Using same certificates in IE, it works as well.
Postman works as well.
FireFox Works as well.

Chrome however it shows certificate length as 0

[image: Chrome Asking for certificate]

[image: Chrome not sending certificate]

And as you can see same certificate is used by OpenSSL and it is sending.

[image]

Any idea what might be the problem?

Update :
I started chrome with debug and saw this, it seems chrome cannot parse my key or cert.

[14836:18604:0927/172254.921:ERROR:ssl_platform_key_util.cc(70)] Could not parse public key.
[17536:16164:0927/172255.100:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -117

Comment: It has to be more than valid, it has to be signed by a signer the server trusts.

Comment: So i have the same certificate using in different method and it works, if that was the case shouldn't the other mthod fail as well ?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. And even more interestingly: the same certificate with the same server is working in Edge based on MS EdgeHTML rendering engine but not on Chromium rendering engine. So I think it must have something to do with Chromium.

Comment: I opened a bug at Chromium project: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1093788

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a problem with the ASN.1 encoding of the Algorithm Parameters in the certificate. The encoding missed a `NULL` value. If you upload your certificate, we can double-check.